# Он сам вызвал пожарных – отловить попугая

Tags: синтаксис

*Он сам вызвал пожарных – **отловить попугая**.*

Как я понимаю, то, что стоит после тире это цель. *для чего он вызвал пожарных*?
Считается это предложение целевым, если оно оформлено "по-другому"? (хочу сказать, без союза *чтобы* и без запятой)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 8):

Возможны **три разных формы** для этого сообщения:

1) Он сам вызвал пожарных, чтобы отловить попугая.  **СПП с придаточным цели.**

2) Он сам вызвал пожарных отловить попугая. **Необособленное обстоятельство цели.**

3) Он сам вызвал пожарных - отловить попугая. **Обособленное обстоятельство цели** со значением дополнительного пояснения (присоединительная конструкция).

Comment: Думаю, что по смыслу здесь подходит только вариант с тире. Обычное уточнение цели вызова выглядит непонятным, поскольку с такой целью пожарных не вызывают - читатель подумает, не ошибка ли вышла. Поэтому нужно обозначить и авторское недоумение. Тире же может замещать подразумеваемый оборот "представьте себе".

Answer (score 3):

Пояснительно-уточняющий член предложения (у Вас - обстоятельство) может отделяться с помощью тире.  Посмотрите, например, [здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=143) или [тут](http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827507.html), § 23.

Answer (score 2):

Мне встречалась другая пунктуация, где "чтобы" заменялось на двоеточие. "Мы подошли к нему: переспросить, что он говорил". Аналогично и "Он сам вызвал пожарных: отловить попугая", то есть вторая часть предложения раскрывает причину событий первой, уточняет её.