# Он сам приказал вызвать пожарных – отловить попугая

Tags: синтаксис

Я нашла в своем анализе такой пример как иллюстрацию к случаю бессоюзного присоединения придаточного следствия к главному предложению:

*Он сам приказал вызвать пожарных **– отловить попугая**.*

Скажите пожалуйста, будет неправильно если я напишу, что фунция тире заменяет союз *чтобы*?

Спасибо!

Comment: Вам отвечали на подобный вопрос.[Повтор вопроса](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418929/%d0%9e%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f)

Comment: спасибо большое! я уже совсем запуталась с этой кучей предложений! : ) спасибо еще раз!!!

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет бессоюзного присоединения придаточного следствия к главному предложению. У Вас - простое предложение.

[Придаточное следствия](http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r2_2_3_8) отвечает на вопрос ***что из этого следует?*** и присоединяется к главному предложению при помощи союза ***так что***.

Вот как выглядит это сложное предложение полностью:

*Однако жена вовремя напомнила ему, что он сам приказал вызвать пожарных — отловить попугая.*

СПП с [придаточном изъяснительным](http://bitclass.ru/rus/theory/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) с союзным словом ***что***.

Поэтому тире в придаточной части не заменяет союз *чтобы*, а обособляет обстоятельство цели.